# Why do I keep getting caught speeding?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I am playing Euro Truck Simulator 2 and driving around doing the Quick Jobs because I've only just started and don't have enough money to purchase my own truck. As it is a simulator there are speed limits on all of the roads and speed cameras placed. Many times I have been in a road marked as national speed limit zone indicated by a white circle with a black line through it but I've been given a speeding ticket for doing 55mph

edit: as an additional example, I just got a speeding ticket on the motorway for doing 55mph as well!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you are doing wrong: Playing a game where driving the speed limit (Or even below it in this case?) is actually enforced and encouraged. :P - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NoFK9KcMlk8

Comment: Not a direct answer, but from a conversation I had whilst in Europe, all their trucks/buses are fitted with monitoring software to tell if they're speeding, how long they've been driving without rest etc. Truck drivers actually need to 'clock on' by inserting their card into the truck, it wont start without it. So it may be that you drift over the speed limit whilst between speed cameras, and you're still getting caught out. Assuming that a 'simulator' would try to be as realistic as possible

Comment: Reminds me of playing GTA and trying to stop at stoplights....

Comment: @Robotnik: A friend f mine designs software for some of those tracking things. GPS position at all times as well as monitoring of speed as you said but also things like how hard the driver is braking when they break (so excessively hard breaking would be detected). Its quite terrifying how much information you can get out of a truck with the rigth interface. ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

55 mph is the speed limit for trucks in most European countries. What you are doing wrong is speeding. You can see the full list for speed limits in the [Wikipedia article for speed limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_limits_by_country).

Here are some examples:

- Germany: 80-100 kph (49-62 mph)
- Italy: 70-80 kph (43-49 mph)
- Poland: 70-80 kph (43-49 mph)
- Austria: lorries with heavy trailer - 80 kph (49 mph)
- Spain: 70-90 kph (43-55.9 mph)

Answer (score 4):

You're doing nothing wrong! There are usually white coloured boards warning about cameras ahead, after that, slow the truck down till you pass a cube like thing on the road, that's the camera. Once you pass it, you're fine! Usually the camera warnings are with speed limit boards before them, so you know how much to speed it down.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing wrong is driving in the UK. They have speed traps everywhere. You get tickets all over the place.

Go to France, and you can drive your truck at 90 km/h, the limiter speed.

Go to Germany and you can drive on the highways at 90 km/hr and you won't get a ticket, even though the limit is 80.

If you slow down for tunnels, towns, and intersections, you won't get many tickets in Europe.

If you go to UK you will get plenty of tickets unless you drive very slow and careful.